# Publish Building using ClickOnce Stalls forever

Tags: c#, clickonce, signtool

We use Click once technology to publish our application. Of late, when trying to do the same the application blocks for ever when the Sign Click once manifest is ticked.  However, if this were to be uniticked or if the application were to published in safe mode with networking prompt , the publish build process doesnot hang. 
On the other hand if the application is run on normal mode with the sign  manifest enabled the application always stops at the publish building process.

Note: The certificate used has not expired 
using the sign tool on the command line works perfectly. I have also repaired VS 2010.
Ending the Signtool process from the taskmanager makes the application active again

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it is trying to contact a timestamp server and failing. Run [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) while you publish and see if you can see any failed http calls. As to *why* it is failing, I don't know, but hopefully it will give you a starting point.

The timestamp service stamps the manifest so that when the app's certificate expires, the client can verify that it was signed while the certificate was still valid.

Comment: Hi sir, is there a way i can disable this checking for timestamp server, i figure out that i have to sign the click once manifest else the application will not be able to access local resoruces.

Comment: I don't think you have control over this if you are using Visual Studio to publish. Try [mageui](http://goo.gl/kVpEx) - open your manifest and click 'Save'. Select your cert and make sure the TimeStamping URI is cleared out. If that works, you can automate it with the command line version of [mage](http://goo.gl/WzrMF). I'm sure msbuild would work as well. However, have you validated with Fiddler that this is actually the problem? If so, it might be easier to try and figure out why your machine can't connect to the timestamping service.