# mage.exe fails to update manifest

Tags: .net-4.0, msbuild, clickonce

we use TFS 2010 and msbuild.

When we build a new test version of our click once application the following command is executed on the build server:

mage.exe -u "our.app.manifest" -if green.ico -fd . -cf "C:\Test\Sources\App\App.Gui\test.pfx" -pwd password

About 12 minutes later we get the following error message:

"Internal error, please try again. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

It has been working for about 2 years when this problem suddenly appear. The certificate is valid until october 2012. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Could you post the msbuild log section regarting this invocation?

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141474) may be similar